# Unable to open solution containing website due to port being less than 1024?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I recently had to remap my solution to a new directory, upon trying to reload the solution in visual studio 2010 I get the error message:

> "Cannot open Web Site 'http ://localhost/XXX'. You must run Visual Studio in the context of an administrator account to create IIS Express sites with ports less than 1024."

This is strange because as far as I can tell, the port defined in the solution file is well above port 1024. And the only advice I can find requires that I open the solution in VS (funny little catch 22 right?).

The solution worked before I remapped and re-downloaded the solution from TFS.

This is in remote apps, so I don't have access to actually run VS as an administrator.

Comment: The message says to open it as an Administrator. Right-click Visual Studio shortcut and choose "Run as Administrator". Then, go to the project settings and correct the port

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running this in remote apps and I'm unable to run as administrator.

Comment: Is this a web site project, or a web application project?

Comment: Then, good luck. I was about to tell you to edit the project file, but there isn't one, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out a solution a while ago, but forgot to post the answer here just in case someone else stumbled across this one day.

If you open the solution file containing the project, you need to remove any instance of 'localhost' where the website in question is referenced. This seems to do the trick.

My guess is VS sees the 'localhost' and assumes you're trying to actually open a site on the local machine, or bind it to that address. Which would explain the port error.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue after updating Visual Studio 2017. I opened up each affected project file and removed the contents in the *IISUrl* and the project reloads correctly. Weird since both *UseIISExpress* and *UseIIS* were set to False.

I also tried typetrice's solution and it worked too.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing since updating from Visual Studio 2017 15.6 to 15.7. The workarounds described here work. I've reported this to Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248129/loading-web-project-fails-in-157-creation-of-the-v.html

Comment: I think this is still fundamentally broken. We were using the `DevelopmentServerPort` to conditionally change the URL used depending on whether or not the developer is using local IIS or IIS Express. Now this port is ignored and IIS Express tries to register the hosting on the defined `IISUrl`.

Comment: This was broken in VS 2017 version 15.7 and then fixed in 15.7.2.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error after upgrading a website from VS 2005 to VS 2012. [cDecker32's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956317/1036274) is correct, but I'm adding some supporting details...

The site was declared like this in the VS 2005 sln file:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "C:\...\EMR\", "EMR", "{6E950F28-C219-492C-B9A3-5480D70475FB}"
```

VS 2012 changed it during the upgrade to reference localhost:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "http://localhost/EMR/", "http://localhost/EMR", "{6E950F28-C219-492C-B9A3-5480D70475FB}"
```

After relaunching VS 2012 with "Run As Administrator" (per the error message's instructions), 'localhost' was removed from the project name, but kept in the path:

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "EMR-Site/EMR", "http://localhost/EMR", "{6E950F28-C219-492C-B9A3-5480D70475FB}"
```

This allowed the solution to load, but the site failed to run at this point; studio complained that you need admin rights to use ports < 1024. I believe it assumes localhost means IIS on port 80.

Manually renaming the path to "\EMR" in both the Project definition and the Source Control section allowed the site to run as it did in VS 2005.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I opened the project in VS2013 but still no problem in VS2012. I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

Open the project file in a text editor and change the following line in the project file:

```
<AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort> -> <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
```

Also, I removed the following line:

```
<DevelopmentServerPort>81</DevelopmentServerPort>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one of the visual studio bug i guess, there is no logical reason for this error. Deleting all visual studio extensions at current project fix the error. After reloading project, you can set the settings how you need.

```
<VisualStudio>
  <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
    <WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>true</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>http://localhost/XXXXX</IISUrl>
      <NTLMAuthentication>True</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
    </WebProjectProperties>
  </FlavorProperties>
</VisualStudio>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case : after delete the csproj.user file, project get loaded.